# how should i let my asp.net queue with other server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, message-queue

Im currently writing a application where i need to let my other server queue base on request and after that, the application from my server send back a small data of whether it's finished, still queueing, how many percent, item id, etc...

Is there any way i can accomplish this? since i dont want my other server to run another Http instance to expose to the outside world and is there anyway to authenticate each call between the 2 server?

Thank you very very very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to need to create a couple of events that you can bind to to provide the information.

Your server object needs to expose a couple of events.  You can then bind to those events giving them a callback which your server object can call at certain points.

When these events are called, your web application can respond to them and possibly update data on the client.

On the client end, I think you'll need to do ajax calls to check status change or something coz I don't think your code behind will be able to update your UI.

If you want code then let me know and I can post some.

The problem is the UI.  Once a page is on the client that's pretty much it.  You need to build into it the ability to do monitoring and that's accomplished via ajax or jQuery.

It all sounds complex but the event wiring is quite straight forward as is the ajax/jQuery stuff.